# On the top of the hill/ at the top of..... Here, are AT/ON interchangeable?

Tags: prepositions

> When we grow older, we'll buy ourselves a place to live in **at** the
>   top of the hill.
>
> When we grow older, we'll buy ourselves a place to live in **on** the
>   top of the hill.

In this context, are **ON/AT** interchangeable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use either one, but they could imply slightly different things.  If you use `on`, it would mean:

```
  H
 /\
/  \
```

but `at` might also mean:

```
 /\H
/  \
```

It is unlikely that you will be misunderstood, but there is that slight ambiguity.  I would take out the word `in` in both cases because it sounds awkward to have two prepositions right next to each other.

Comment: Bonus points for the ascii art.

Answer (score 3):

In your sentance, the words 'at' and 'on' are almost, but not exactly the same in meaning.

'At the top' implies the place is located very near the top of the hill. It might be on the top of the hill, but it might also just be close to the top of the hill, or even slightly under the surface of the top of the hill.

'On the top' implies a more precise location; the location is on the peak or top of the highest point of the hill.